# Django authentication between views

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-templates, view

I'm having some trouble using the django authentication
 i have a view that uses the decorator @login_required.

Once logged the user will procede to a page, fill some data and use a post request to access the next page, however when trying to go back to the previous page django will show the log in form again.
Is there a way to prevent this?

I was thinking on using a button to go back with a post with the session so django wont ask for login again but i'm not sure if that can be done.

Comment: "Trying to go back" using the browser back button or using a button that is part of the web page?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want a logged-in user to see the login form, I suggest you redirect the user to another page if they are already logged in:

```
def login_page(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('some-other-page')
    [...the rest of the login-page logic goes here; pass form through via context...]
```

You could also show the logged-in user a message on the login page telling them that they are already logged in using template logic:

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
    <p>You are already logged in</p>
{% else %}
    <form>
        {{ form }}
        <input type='submit'>Submit</input>
    </form>
{% endif %}
```